# Why change in a record in Core Data sending NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete event?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

I have a UITableViewController which implements NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. In

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
```

I am loading record from an entity. Now when I am updating a record in that entity has NSFetchedResultsChangeType always NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete and deletes my objects. I would think it should just update as I am updating record not deleting it.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        NSLog(@"object deleted %d",
              indexPath.row);
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:

        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        NSLog(@"object moved %d",
              indexPath.row);
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                           arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
}}
```

**EDIT 1:**

It also seems to be not inserting while I am first saving the object. Infact at that point didChangeObject is not even fired.

**EDIT 2**

More information:
I use same table for different predicates. I have a split view and left and right views are both table views. In left I show some categories and on based on selection in left I configure the view in right. Configuration first deletes the cache and then changes the predicate of NSFetchedResultsController and then do performFetch on that. In background I find updated objects for the selected category and either insert new objects or update existing ones. Now adding new objects don't show up automatically in table view and updating objects is causing a delete. I update categories in left table view from a different NSFetchedResultsController and that works fine. Both NSFetchedResultsController use different cache file. If I don't change predicate then everything works fine with objects from all the categories. Predicate is to fetch records from selected category.

Comment: Can you post your entire didChangeObject method?

Comment: @Salil Did you find solution to this? I have a similar problem. Any suggestions?